# Computer slow on booting from SSD or USB

Tags: boot, ssd, motherboard, performance

I have got an Asus P10S-M WS motherboard, a Intel i7-6700 CPU, a SSD with Ubuntu 18.04 installed and a 8GB DDR4 ram stick.

When i try to boot it from the SSD it takes a long time to load the login screen (about 2min). Also, when I try to load a live USB its more of the same, it takes ages to load. Once its loaded it works really quick, so i dont think theres a problem with the SSD.

I have already checked all the connections to the motherboard, updated the BIOS to the last version, changed SSD sata cable, changed the sata port in the motherboard. I also tried a different RAM stick and nothing changed. 
The motherboard doesnt detect any failures on boot, but this isnt normal.

Hope some one can help me with this because i dont know what else to try.

Comment: How have you installed the OS? UEFI ir Legacy? Modern hardware requires UEFI mode for optimal performance.

Comment: Tried also in UEFI mode and the result is the same, really long boot time from SSD or the USB.

Comment: "Tried also" suggests this isn't your first choice but it should be ALWAYS. Troubleshoot from there, not from legacy mode.

Comment: Okay, ill do it that way from now on. But that isnt the problem, im starting to think theres some hardware problem but what hw problem could make the boot really slow and then once it starts up work correctly?

Comment: Some boards are slow in POST, slow to check and initialize hardware. Some UEFI/BIOS settings may have an impact.